# Will hmac-sha1 slow down the performance?

Tags: encryption, md5, hmac, hmacsha1

There is a website with lots of HTTP traffic. There is a MD5 HASH field in HTTP header. Now I want to change use HMAC-SHA1 to encrypt the data instead. Will the server load increase a lot with HMAC-SHA1?

Comment: hmac-sha1 is not encryption but hash that takes two extra blocks of data derived from a key. Sha1 calculation is about twice as cpu intensive as md5.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: and HMAC does two hashes, so hmac-sha1 should be about 4x MD5.

Comment: Hmac does just 2 64-byte blocks more hashes than a corresponding non-key based hash. For any larger lengths the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

This question can not be answered meaningfully. Does it take more computational power to count SHA1 than MD5? Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723941/308851 . Will this affect your traffic meaningfully? Well, that depends on how big a percentage this hashing takes currently. Ie. if you are running even just somewhat complex page which queries a database then calculating a single hash won't give you a meaningful difference.

You yourself need to benchmark this.