# SHA-256 or MD5 for file integrity

Tags: file, hash, md5, sha256

I know that SHA-256 is favored over MD5 for security, etc., but, if I am to use a method to only check file integrity (that is, nothing to do with password encryption, etc.), is there any advantage of using SHA-256?

Since MD5 is 128-bit and SHA-256 is 256-bit (therefore twice as big)...

1. Would it take up to twice as long to compute the hash?
2. Where time is not of essence, like in a backup program, and file integrity is all that is needed, would anyone argue against MD5 for a different algorithm, or even suggest a different technique?
3. Does using MD5 produce a checksum?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: Neither MD5 nor SHA-* encrypt anything. They are hash functions.

Comment: @delnan Actually, I'm happy you've picked up on that, thank you. But, isn't a hash representation of something an encryption?

Comment: No. For starters, an encryption is reversible (by definition) while a hash cannot be reversed (by the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: Seems like a hash is more secure somehow, but I appreciate the clarification :)

Comment: Well, the two are fundamentally different and consequently, the various kinds of attack on one of the two don't even make sense for the other, so "more secure" doesn't make a lot sense IMHO. Care to clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Just that one is designed to be undone (encrypted/decrypted) whilst the other isn't!

Comment: Well, they are, but that just means they serve different purposes and are consequently attacked differently. For hash function, the most common attack is producing a collision because that's how you defeat hash-based security measurements (e.g. hashing passwords, or signing certificates). You don't hide anything by storing only its hash, because then it's "lost"/inaccessible for *everybody*, not just for attackers.

Comment: @delnan thank you again for taking the time to explain this. I will now look up collisions!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Both SHA256 and MD5 are hashing algorithms. They take your input data, in this case your file, and output a 256/128-bit number. This number is a checksum. There is no encryption taking place because an infinite number of inputs can result in the same hash value, although in reality collisions are rare.

SHA256 takes somewhat more time to calculate than MD5, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943/is-calculating-an-md5-hash-less-cpu-intensive-than-sha-1-or-sha-2).

Offhand, I'd say that MD5 would be probably be suitable for what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but as an off topic question, are you saying that encryption must produce a unique 'code'/'id' like a GUID?

Comment: @DaveRook How else would you then decrypt the message?

Comment: @PaulManta - I have no idea, as I'm only doing this for integrity I've never actually considered encryption like this, but this is brilliant to know. Thank you.

Comment: @dave I think there's a bit of confusion on the topic because SHA is called a cryptographic hash. What that means (I'm far from an expert) is that you can use it to hash passwords. That way if an attacker gets your user password file, he can't used the hashes to reconstruct the original passwords. Encryption is different in that it is meant to be reversible.

Comment: @Dave you mentioned below that you were looking for a list of hash functions.  Have a look at the wikipedia article on Hash functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: After running benchmarks on dotnet 6, it now appears that sha256 is faster than md5 so this answer is outdated

Answer (score 27):

Every answer seems to suggest that you need to use secure hashes to do the job but all of these are tuned to be slow to force a bruteforce attacker to have lots of computing power and depending on your needs this may not be the best solution.

There are algorithms specifically designed to hash files as fast as possible to check integrity and comparison (`murmur`, `XXhash`...). Obviously these are not designed for security as they don't meet the requirements of a secure hash algorithm (i.e. randomness) but have low collision rates *for large messages*. This features make them ideal if you are not looking for security but speed.

Examples of this algorithms and comparison can be found in this excellent answer: [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed).

As an example, we at our Q&A site use `murmur3` to hash the images uploaded by the users so we only store them once even if users upload the same image in several answers.

Answer (score 25):

To 1):
Yes, on most CPUs, SHA-256 is about only 40% as fast as MD5.

To 2):
I would argue for a different algorithm than MD5 in such a case. I would definitely prefer an algorithm that is considered safe. However, this is more a feeling. Cases where this matters would be rather constructed than realistic, e.g. if your backup system encounters an example case of an attack on an MD5-based certificate, you are likely to have two files in such an example with different data, but identical MD5 checksums. For the rest of the cases, it doesn't matter, because MD5 checksums have a collision (= same checksums for different data) virtually only when provoked intentionally.
I'm not an expert on the various hashing (checksum generating) algorithms, so I can not suggest another algorithm. Hence this part of the question is still open.
Suggested further reading is [Cryptographic Hash Function - File or Data Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#File_or_data_identifier) on Wikipedia. Also further down on that page there is a list of cryptographic hash algorithms.

To 3):
MD5 is an algorithm to calculate checksums. A checksum calculated using this algorithm is then called an MD5 checksum.

Answer (score 12):

The underlying MD5 algorithm is no longer deemed secure, thus while md5sum is well-suited for identifying known files in situations that are not security related, it should not be relied on if there is a chance that files have been purposefully and maliciously tampered. In the latter case, the use of a newer hashing tool such as sha256sum is highly recommended.

So, if you are simply looking to check for file corruption or file differences, when the source of the file is trusted, MD5 should be sufficient.  If you are looking to verify the integrity of a file coming from an untrusted source, or over from a trusted source over an unencrypted connection, MD5 is not sufficient.

Another commenter noted that Ubuntu and others use MD5 checksums.  Ubuntu has moved to PGP and SHA256, in addition to MD5, but the documentation of the stronger verification strategies are more difficult to find.  See the [HowToSHA256SUM page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToSHA256SUM) for more details.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but thank you for making this point!  If you are using checksums to verify that an attacker isn't screwing with your files, MD5 is a terrible idea.  If the attacker knows what they're doing, they could theoretically find the right collision that'd enable them to execute their code without altering the file's checksum, thus eluding any checksum-based security verification.

SHA algos perform well enough on modern CPUs and scale a lot better (as file sizes get bigger, so too must our checksums).  If you're dealing with large HD video files, I'd use SHA-512.

Answer (score 11):

1. No, it's less fast but not that slow
2. For a backup program it's maybe necessary to have something even faster than MD5

All in all, I'd say that MD5 in addition to the file name is absolutely safe. SHA-256 would just be slower and harder to handle because of its size.

You could also use something less secure than MD5 without any problem. If nobody tries to hack your file integrity this is safe, too.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is I don't know what else I could use! I'm not asking for a recommendation and I am happy to research other approaches, but can you suggest something other than MD5/SHA256?

Comment: Depends on the programming language and runtime environment you're using.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, on most CPUs, SHA-256 is two to three times slower than MD5, though not primarily because of its longer hash. See other answers here and the answers to [this Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943).
2. Here's a backup scenario where MD5 would not be appropriate:

   - Your backup program hashes each file being backed up. It then stores
     each file's data by its hash, so if you're backing up the same file
     twice you only end up with one copy of it.
   - An attacker can cause the system to backup files they control.
   - The attacker knows the MD5 hash of a file they want to remove from the
     backup.
   - The attacker can then use the known weaknesses of MD5 to craft a new
     file that has the same hash as the file to remove. When that file is
     backed up, it will replace the file to remove, and that file's backed up
     data will be lost.
   - This backup system could be strengthened a bit (and made more efficient)
     by not replacing files whose hash it has previously encountered, but
     then an attacker could prevent a target file with a known hash from
     being backed up by preemptively backing up a specially constructed bogus
     file with the same hash.
   - Obviously most systems, backup and otherwise, do not satisfy the
     conditions necessary for this attack to be practical, but I just wanted
     to give an example of a situation where SHA-256 would be preferable to
     MD5. Whether this would be the case for the system you're creating
     depends on more than just the characteristics of MD5 and SHA-256.
3. Yes, cryptographic hashes like the ones generated by MD5 and SHA-256 are a type of checksum.

Happy hashing!

Answer (score 6):

It is technically approved that MD5 is faster than SHA256 so in just verifying file integrity it will be sufficient and better for performance.

You are able to checkout the following resources:

- [Speed Comparison of Popular Crypto Algorithms](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html)
- [Comparison of cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptographic_hash_functions)

Comment: Ah, and the link you have provided also shows other algorythms. I guess I need to find which ones are available to .NET now and find the quickest. Thank you

Comment: @DaveRook In addition, If you look arround for famous website such as Sun, Ubuntu and others, you may notice that they supply MD5 checksum for files integrity. This may support its value for such tasks.