# How to hash string more efficiently? md5 vs sha256

Tags: sql, postgresql

Which function better to use- faster, less collisions:

```
md5('somelonglonglongstring')
```

or

```
encode(digest('somelonglonglongstring', 'sha256'), 'hex')
```

What data type to use for sha256? varchar(64)?
Or any other function is better?

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139727/sha-256-or-md5-for-file-integrity) which compares MD5 and SHA seems to be at least relevant to your question.