# Passlib.hash won't import

Tags: python, password-encryption

I am trying to import passlib.hash with

```
from passlib.hash import md5_crypt
```

But I get the error message

```
ImportError: No module named passlib.hash
```

Why is this? Can I even us passlib.hash anymore to encrypt passwords? I know there was another question similar to this, but there was only one answer and that didn't work.

And if passlib.hash isn't the best way to go, what are some other solutions out there that work?

Comment: First. NO MD5 :@
Secondly. Works fine for me.

Comment: Still not working for me. Still says no module named passlib.hash. What do you suggest I try or do?

Comment: `pip install passlib --upgrade`

Comment: would you suggest hashlib.sha512()?

Comment: @JakobBowyer I mean, unless you're using MD5 for something not cryptographically secure, like a checksum/file fingerprint.

Comment: @aruisdante sha all the things

Comment: @JakobBowyer MD5 is generally a [good bit faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722943/is-calculating-an-md5-hash-less-cpu-intensive-than-sha-1-or-sha-2) than sha. There is a reason most places still use it as a checksum/file fingerprint hash. Definitely do NOT use it as a way of encrypting data though.