# why md5 is slower than sha1 in python 2.7.11

Tags: python, hash

I have tested the speed of md5, sha1, crc32, the result shows that md5 is slower than sha1, I am confused about it becasue sha1 is more compliacted than md5.

I executed my test python script to hash a png image(you can use an image whatever you want) 10000 times like:
crc_vs_md5.py  C:\Users\bigwalnut\Desktop\def.png 10000

result(unit: s):
md5:  0.122737341241
sha1:  0.0984247229759
crc32:  0.0577822398549

Here is the code:

```
from hashlib import md5, sha1
from zlib import crc32
import sys
import time

numberoftime = 0
content = None

def getMd5():
    for x in range(0, numberoftime):
        mdfive = md5()
        mdfive.update(content)
        mdfive.hexdigest()

def getSha1():
    for x in range(0, numberoftime):
        sha1Obj = sha1()
        sha1Obj.update(content)
        sha1Obj.hexdigest()


def getCrc32():
    for x in range(0, numberoftime):
        crc32(content) & 0xffffffff


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('You must enter: filename, numberoftime')
    exit(1)
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print('Only filename, numberoftime is permitted')
    exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]
numberoftime = int(sys.argv[2])
print filename, numberoftime

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

start = time.clock()
getMd5()
stop = time.clock()
print "md5: ", stop - start

start = time.clock()
getSha1()
stop = time.clock()
print "sha1: ", stop - start

start = time.clock()
getCrc32()
stop = time.clock()
print "crc32: ", stop - start
```

Comment: The [results on this link](http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/02/05/performance-test-md5-sha1-sha256-sha512/) conflict with yours.

Comment: Good time to learn about [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to get more accurate results.

Comment: @Selcuk, I am sorry i wrote a wrong title, md5 is slower than sha1 in my test.

Answer (score 0):

Python borrows OpenSSL primitives for most cryptographic purposes; while it's not definitive, [this post](http://omnifarious.livejournal.com/363945.html) implies that the OpenSSL developers, knowing MD5 is broken, probably haven't put much effort into optimizing MD5, while SHA1 was intensively optimized; MD5 may be simpler algorithmically, but if the code is less heavily optimized than the SHA1 code, then the already small advantage MD5 has won't be noticeable.

[On another post comparing OpenSSL's MD5 and SHA1 implementations (without the Python wrapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324732/364696), it looks like core OpenSSL is usually faster at SHA1, though it has varied by version/build (SHA1 was faster on OSX 10.8 and 10.10, slower on 10.9).